# how to pipe contents of large tar.gz file to STDOUT?

Tags: bash

I have a `large.tar.gz` file containing about 1 million files, out of which about 1/4 of them are html files, and I want to parse a few lines of each of the html files within.

I want to avoid having to extract the contents of large `large.tar.gz` into a folder and then parse the html files, instead I would like to know how can I pipe the contents of the html files in the `large.tar.gz` straight to `STDOUT` so that I can grep/parse out the information I want from them?

I presume there must be some magic like:

```
tar -special_flags large.tar.gz | grep_only_files_with_extension html | xargs -n1 head -n 99999 | ./parse_contents.pl -
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should consider checking `<command> --help` or `<command> -h` before posting a question, most of the times it's less than 30 lines and one of them contains the needed flag

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use this with GNU tar to extract a tgz to stdout:

```
tar -xOzf large.tar.gz --wildcards '*.html' | grep ...
```

---

> `-O, --to-stdout`: extract files to standard output

Comment: @Yaron: I would expect it to use zcat, while `pigz -dc` is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Info for followers: here -O is "capital o", not zero. I loose some time before understand that.

Comment: The big O is for Out. Just under the `-O, --to-stdout` option in the man page is also `--to-command=COMMAND` which might be maybe even more useful in some of the cases where you would use stdout as well.

Comment: What are the memory requirements of this? Do I have to store the entire contents in memory?