# Reading NetCDF file within tar.gz file without extracting the tar file

Tags: matlab, tar, netcdf

I am looking for a way to read data from netcdf format files stored within a tar file without extracting the file first. The reason for this is we have thousands of such data file of significant file size each, and extracting them would require significant disk space and time.

Is there a way I can achieve this using Matlab or other ways? some online topics discuss reading text file within tar file without extracting using linux, but not netcdf file.

I see there may be ways to do this on a unix/Linux machine, but is there a way to do the same in a Windows operating system?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34176788/3776858) might help to extract file from tar to stdout.

Comment: You may need to [mount](https://superuser.com/questions/265772/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-tar-file) the tar.gz file as a file system using `archivemount`.

Comment: This can be carried out calling Java inside matlab.

Comment: Incidentally, if the file is zipped to reduce its size, it is a *terrible* coiche. NetCDF4 supports transparent compression and chunking, which effectively solves the same problem much more elegantly and with much less effort from the end user.

Comment: I have about 12000 tar files (~1 terabyte), and restricted to Windows machine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Matlab support and they gave me a solution that reduced the tar extraction time significantly.

Solution: Instead of using Matlab “untar” command, use direct system command as : system(‘tar xzvf filename.tar.gz *.nc’).

This reduced extraction time for a file from 13 minute to 8 seconds.