# YARN logs .gz format how to decompress using command

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, logging, gzip, hadoop-yarn

When trying to get the YARN logs for a Spark application the logs seems to be compressed to gzip format, how can the same be decompressed. **LogType:stdout.gz**

```
LogType:stdout.gz
Log Upload Time:Tue Jan 21 03:38:17 +0000 2020
LogLength:1074
Log Contents:
       řϲ£8Ưy
½ þ!    ߶⌔kRك²[µ'1Î
pv歷±ɄA²]ö!券ߏ£²¢ڶ蕷eź6f÷-нOϯ«¿^��zùǪ¼¿Cû¯UQ
```

The logs are fetched using the `yarn logs -applicationId <applicationId> > file_name.log`  is there something that needs to be append to the command to decompress the files while outputing the results.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156324/133356

Comment: @bob is there any commands to unzip when fetching the logs from the yarn instead as its distributed the files will be in different location and the yarn command gets them in a single hit

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look into this approach:

```
gunzip -c stdout.gz | myScript.pl -o myoutfile.txt -i -
```

or you can go with:

```
zcat stdout.gz > yarnstdout
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418771/uncompress-and-pipe-the-output-to-script

Similar questions:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156261/unzipping-a-gz-file-without-removing-the-gzipped-file/156324#156324
[how to pipe contents of large tar.gz file to STDOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176788/how-to-pipe-contents-of-large-tar-gz-file-to-stdout)

Cheers!